# Power Apps - Hide a Drop-down field based on a Text field containing value or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-forms, sharepoint-fields

I have a Power Apps form (based on an SP list) in which I need to Hide some fields based on whether or not a text field contains any value.  I can't figure out how to add hideable sections like InfoPath, so I'm trying this route. "PMO Approval" is my drop-down field, and I only want this field visible if my Text field, "Project Manager" contains a value.  It's simple logic, but I'm not sure how to express it in PowerApps.

This would be cleaner/easier to have an entire section I can hide based on the "project Manager" text field, but I can't find where to add a section in Power Apps. But I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Visible` property of data card for "PMO Approval" field to:

```
Not(IsBlank(DataCardValue2.Text))
```

Replace `DataCardValue2` in above formula by name of text input control for "Project Manager" field.